# How does ranking work?

Tags: overwatch

How does ranking work? I have played Overwatch a lot i'm but new to Competitive Overwatch, currently im ranked 4,000, is being rank 100 good or being 5,000 good?

Comment: Also, new to comp. Overwatch, but already rank 4000? What are you, a pro Genji?

Answer (score 4):

In the new Season 2 meta, the ranking system has changed. Whereas it used to be ranked on a 1-100 scale, with wins and losses contributing to fractions of a point, the system has changed for season 2.

Now, rankings are on a scale of 1-5000, allowing for greater representation of skill level. The higher the number, the greater a players represented skill level. Additionally, wins and losses contribute whole number points. Players are rewarded "Icons" on their profile (placed instead of their profile number-ranking during ranked games), after reaching intervals on the 1-5000 scale. Once these rankings have been achieved, your number can drop below the ranking threshold, but you will still retain the same "Rank". A scale can be seen here:

[image: Rankings]

Comment: Do we know if there's *any* individual performance component? Last season it seemed 100% wins/losses.

Comment: @DCShannon This time around, ties are a possibility. I'm not sure how these affect your rating (I haven't played Season 2 quite yet) but I imagine it does not affect your rank.

Comment: @DCShannon In both season 1 and 2, individual performance played a part in determining rating. People who always played together could end up with different ratings, with usually the supports ranking lower than the tanks or DPS classes.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer This was addressed by Blizzard, and performance from certain supports has been adjusted to match what a DPS or Tank might get.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I'm afraid that doesn't match up with what's been observed so far.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer No kidding? Color me corrected then, I could have sworn Blizzard claimed they fixed this at some point.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Oh they probably did change *something*, but as long as individual performance is factored into ranking, placements are going to be skewed one way or another.